# JSON_ARRAY_APPEND in sequelize with NodeJs

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, hapi

I am trying to update a JSON column (let say, `history`) of MySQL. I have an object like:

`{statue: 'pending', date: 'current_date'}`

on using `MODEL.update({history: {statue: 'pending', date: 'current_date'}})` it is working fine, (first entry)

but when I am trying to append it like:

```
MODEL.update({ history: Sequelize.fn(
          'JSON_ARRAY_APPEND',
          Sequelize.col('history'),
          '$',
          `${Sequelize.fn('JSON_OBJECT', 'status', status, 'updated_at', new Date())}`
        )})
```

it is not working.

I don't want to use JSON.stringify() (it is working with it).
But I want to store the proper object array.

Can anyone help

Comment: I am still looking for some answer for this, though I have managed this with simple JSON.strigify.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-merge-preserve)

```js
const newHistory = {
  updated_at: new Date(),
};


await MODEL.update(
  {
    history: fn("JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE", 
      col("history"), 
      literal(`'${JSON.stringify(newHistory)}'`)
    ),
  },
  { where: { id: id } },
);
```

If your JSON is an array, here is to append array.

```js
const newHistory = {
  status: 'pending',
  updated_at: new Date(),
  date: new Date(),
};


await MODEL.update(
  {
    history: fn("JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE", 
      col("history"), 
      literal(`'[${JSON.stringify(newHistory)}]'`)
    ),
  },
  { where: { id: id } },
);
```

If it's still error, you can check the log, then try to run it in native command MySQL
https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/getting-started/#logging

Answer (score 0):

I'm french, so my english it'll be bad.

The solution of your probleme is simple.
just remove `` around your last `Sequelize.fn`.

Replace: `${Sequelize.fn('JSON_OBJECT', 'status', status, 'updated_at', new Date())}`

By: ${Sequelize.fn('JSON_OBJECT', 'status', status, 'updated_at', new Date())}